# How can I generate a sample from the distribution $P(x) = \frac{exp(-(x^2-\mu)^2)}{\sum_{\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}}exp(-(\bar{x}^2-\mu)^2)}$

Tags: probability

I wish to generate samples from generate a sample from the distribution $$P(x) = \frac{\exp(-(x^2-\mu)^2)}{\sum_{\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}}\exp(-(\bar{x}^2-\mu)^2)}$$.

The unnormalized probability is $\exp(-(x^2-\mu)^2)$. This suggests that points for which $(x^2-\mu)^2$ is small will be preferred by the distribution. Hence, an 'approximate' strategy can be to sample $\epsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and then specify $x = \pm \sqrt{\mu + \epsilon}$. This is obviously not a correct strategy as can be observed by finding the correct distribution of $\sqrt(\mu + \epsilon)$. However, I was wondering if this is strategy is 'approximately' correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is meant by the notation $\sum_{\bar x\in\mathbb R}$?

Comment: Sum over all real numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the sum at the denominator be replaced with an integral ? Up to a normalizing constant, your target distribution is :

$$ p(x) \propto \exp \big( -(x^{2}-\mu^{2})^2 \big). $$

Its normalized version would be :

$$ \tilde{p}(x) = Cp(x) \quad \text{with} \quad \frac{1}{C}=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp\big( -(t^2 - \mu^2)^2 \big) \, dt. $$

Given my humble knowledge, this is not a *known* distribution on $\mathbb{R}$. In addition to this, it seems that the cumulative distribution function (for the normalized density) cannot be obtained in closed-form.

I would suggest sampling from $\tilde{p}$ this distribution using the **Metropolis-Hastings algorithm**. This algorithm is a Monte Carlo Markov Chain (MCMC) method which allows you to sample from a probability distribution which is known *only up to a normalizing constant*. It is particularly interesting when the normalizing constant cannot be computed in closed-form.

Comment: Yup.  It should have been an integral.  I can use Langevin mcmc or Hamiltonian mcmc to sample from it.

Comment: If the problem is like this, then it is just the $\mathcal{N}(\mu^2, \frac {1} {2})$ distribution; nothing special.

Comment: @BGM : It would be if the target density was 

$$ p(x) \propto \exp\big( -( {\color{red}{x}} - \mu^2 )^2 \big). $$

However, it is not.

Comment: OK sorry I miss it. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp(-(x%5E2-m)%5E2),+x+%3D+-inf+to+x+%3D+inf The normalizing constant is in terms of the Bessel function.